# Dice Game in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have three issues in a vb.net program I am working on. I am creating a dice game where a user can click roll and it will randomly roll and show them the pictures of the dice they rolled. They can chose how many chips they want to play and what number they are betting on. They roll three dice each go.

Here are the issues:

Duplicates - When the user clicks rolls and the random generated numbers, two of them are the same, it will not show one of them. It should show one of them

Images moving into Pictureboxes - I'm trying to get the dice images to move into pictureboxes, better than just having things become visible if played.

Picture of gui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdFB.png

Current code:

```
 Dim do1 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    Dim do2 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    Dim do3 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    Dim do4 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    Dim do5 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
    Dim do6 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)

    ''Assign the appropriate image based on each die's value.
    d1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d1)), Image)
    d2.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d2)), Image)
    d3.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d3)), Image)
    d4.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d1)), Image)
    d5.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d2)), Image)
    d6.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", d3)), Image)

    Dim iNumber As Integer
    Dim iNumber2 As Integer
    Dim iNumber3 As Integer

    'purpose is to roll the dice and play the game. 
    'variables and declarations are here.
    Dim chips As Integer = 100


    If chkBet1.Checked = False And ChkBet2.Checked = False And chkBet3.Checked = False And chkBet4.Checked = False And chkBet5.Checked = False And chkBet6.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a number to play")
    Else

        If txtChip1.Text = "" AndAlso txtChip2.Text = "" AndAlso txtChip3.Text = "" AndAlso txtChip4.Text = "" AndAlso txtChip5.Text = "" AndAlso txtChip6.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter an amount.")
        Else

            'here we are randomizing the numbers for the game. 
            'iNumber = Int((6 * rnd()) + 1)
            'iNumber2 = Int((6 * rnd()) + 1)
            'iNumber3 = Int((6 * rnd()) + 1)

            'this will show the dice if the number generated between 1-6 is automatically chosen. 
            If iNumber = 1 Then
                d1.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber = 2 Then
                d2.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber = 3 Then
                d3.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber = 4 Then
                d4.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber = 5 Then
                d5.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber = 6 Then
                d6.Visible = True
            End If

            'this will show for the second dice. 
            If iNumber2 = 1 Then
                d1.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 2 Then
                d2.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 3 Then
                d3.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 4 Then
                d4.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 5 Then
                d5.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 6 Then
                d6.Visible = True
            End If

            'this will show for the third dice. 
            If iNumber3 = 1 Then
                d1.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 2 Then
                d2.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 3 Then
                d3.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 4 Then
                d4.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 5 Then
                d5.Visible = True
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 6 Then
                d6.Visible = True
            End If

            ''this part is for the chips that they win. If they bet one chip, and one dice rolls a one, they got two chips. 
            If do1 = 1 AndAlso chkBet1.Checked Then
                chips = "2"
            ElseIf do2 = 2 AndAlso ChkBet2.Checked Then
                chips = "4"
            ElseIf do3 = 3 AndAlso chkBet3.Checked Then
                chips = "6"
            ElseIf iNumber = 4 AndAlso chkBet4.Checked Then
                chips = "8"
            ElseIf iNumber = 5 AndAlso chkBet5.Checked Then
                chips = "10"
            ElseIf iNumber = 6 AndAlso chkBet6.Checked Then
                chips = "12"
            End If

            ''second chip possible winnings. 
            If iNumber2 = 1 AndAlso chkBet1.Checked Then
                chips = "2"
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 2 AndAlso ChkBet2.Checked Then
                chips = "4"
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 3 AndAlso chkBet3.Checked Then
                chips = "6"
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 4 AndAlso chkBet4.Checked Then
                chips = "8"
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 5 AndAlso chkBet5.Checked Then
                chips = "10"
            ElseIf iNumber2 = 6 AndAlso chkBet6.Checked Then
                chips = "12"
            End If

            'third chip possible winnings. 
            If iNumber3 = 1 AndAlso chkBet1.Checked Then
                chips = "2"
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 2 AndAlso ChkBet2.Checked Then
                chips = "4"
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 3 AndAlso chkBet3.Checked Then
                chips = "6"
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 4 AndAlso chkBet4.Checked Then
                chips = "8"
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 5 AndAlso chkBet5.Checked Then
                chips = "10"
            ElseIf iNumber3 = 6 AndAlso chkBet6.Checked Then
                chips = "12"
            End If

            'chips are added up here by all
            'chips = iNumber + chips '+ iNumber2 + iNumber3
            lblChips.Text = chips
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the duplicates issue. What is the problem?

Comment: In the String.Format call where you have d1, d2, etc, shouldn't that be do1, do2, etc?  In other words the name of the image in your projects resources.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you have 6 picture boxes.  I thought that you were only rolling three dice?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same picture boxes for each die.  It looks like you should have just 3 picture boxes, one for each die, and they should always be visible.  Then when you determine which value is rolled on the die, change the image in the picture box to match.  Store the 6 images as resources.

I have 1 button and 3 picture boxes on the form.  I also have 6 images (one for each die) embedded in the resources for my project.  I have this code to display the correct image on each picture box, based on a random number, each time I click the button:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Dim rnd As New Random()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Get a random digit from 1 to 6 for each die.  
        Dim die1 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
        Dim die2 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)
        Dim die3 As Integer = rnd.Next(1, 7)

        'Assign the appropriate image based on each die's value.
        PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", die1)), Image)
        PictureBox2.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", die2)), Image)
        PictureBox3.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("Die{0}", die3)), Image)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Additional Information:

```
I created 6 .png files, one for each side of a die.  I named them Die1.png, Die2.png, etc. and then added them as resources to my project.
```

Comment: nothing happens when I entered the code you gave when I clicked roll. Is there anyway you could assist further?